# Simplified test for non-empty variable

Tags: php

I am maintaining some old PHP code and I find many places in the code a test for a variable being non-empty of the following form:

`if (!(isset($field_name) && strlen($field_name) > 0))`

To my way of thinking, the following much simpler form would do exactly the same thing:

```
if ($field_name)
```

Am I missing some subltety whereby the more complex form is more precise? I have tended to use the simpler form any place where I need to add new code.

Comment: You should check out the [list of values considered false](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) in PHP. Those being the boolean false, the integer 0, the float 0.0, an empty string, a string "0", an array with zero elements, null and SimpleXML objects created from empty tags.

Comment: I neglected to specify that 0 or other falsy values are illegal in our system. So I did not clearly state the intent. My feeling is that there is value in the answers and I will perhaps accept one of them as the "answer". I believe that the first line above, regardless of its precision, is overly complicated. In part because it is a compound condition with one condition negated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `empty()` to replace your first line:

```
if (!empty($field_name))
```

The problem with your second example is that it will generate a warning if the variable is not set. Both `empty()` and `isset()` will not generate a warning for non-existing variables.

Note that you always have to account for possible values so if your value can be `0` or `'0'`, this will not work as after `$var = 0;`, `empty($var)` will evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

They do *not* do the same thing. The first code sample:

1. Checks if `$field_name` exists (I figure the `!` is unintentional as it doesn't make sense the way it is written)
2. Checks if `$field_name` has a string length greater than zero

The second code sample:

1. Checks if the variable has a Boolean `true` value
2. Will throw an error if `$field_name` is not set.

The first snippet is *clear* and *precise* in its intent and performs a specific task.

The second snippet is very basic and only verifies the variable has a Boolean true value (and there are better ways to do that). If `$field_name` contains a string "0" this snippet will cause a hard to spot bug as it will fail as "0" evaluates to false. The first snippet would catch this.

Answer (score 0):

if ($field) will fail if $field is null, 0, 0.00, false or anything that can be casted false

if(!isset($field))

will fail if $field has not been declared at all

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the code you found is odd. It should probably be either:

```
if(!(isset($field_name)) { ... do something }
```

or

```
if(isset($field_name) && strlen($field_name) > 0 )  { ... do something }
```

...As you can appreciate, there is no need to test the length of a variable that is not defined.

However, `if($field_name)` is not the same as `if(!(isset($field_name))`, and the difference is not subtle. Indeed, the former will earn you a `Undefined variable: fieldname` if by some stroke of bad luck `$field_name` is not defined.

**What's the difference?**

1. `if($field_name)` tests if the existing variable `$field_name` [evaluates to `TRUE`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). For instance, it's value might be "my dog", and that evaluates to `TRUE`
2. `if(!(isset($field_name))` tests if the variable `$field_name` exists at all.